# Adding a user id field into the Meteor.Users collection of Accounts package

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor, user-accounts

I am new to meteor and i am trying to do my first project in meteor on document management system. I want to add a new field for storing the user id of each user inside the Meteor.Users collection of Accounts package.

Answer (score 1):

Meteor adds a `_id` field to all documents automatically for you. You don't need to add this yourself. It's already done for you.

Comment: Sorry, i do not mean the _id  which is automatically generated for each user. I want to add a field for storing the employee id of each employees . Is it possible to  add such a field inside the Meteor.users collection.If it is possible to add that inside the profile, can u please help me with the code?

Comment: Yes it is. You can use Meteor.createUser I think. Check the documentation for it. Also check out useraccounts package to help with this stuff